# PHP Mail Only Works Sometimes After Migration to VPS

Tags: php, email, hosting, vps

I'm having a very strange situation happening with PHP mail() after migrating some sites over to a VPS.

I have a site that I had on a shared hosting plan. On the site, there are contact forms and other such forms that are handled by PHP scripts. The PHP mail() function is used to send off e-mails with the info in them.

And then I have e-mails for that domain (I'll call it example.com for these purposes). These e-mails' MX records are pointing to Google Apps for Business which is where they have been pointing for years. When the site was on shared hosting, the PHP mail() function worked great and all e-mails received the info that was sent out.

Recently, I've moved the site to a VPS and moved the example.com DNS records to point away from the shared hosting and into a folder in the VPS.

The original shared hosting plan was with 123-reg (a British host) which is also where the example.com domain is currently register. The VPS is at GoDaddy.

I've tested sending an e-mail to my personal e-mail address (which is at GoDaddy) and I receive it successfully. I then tried to send a direct e-mail to the e-mails at example.com and they received those e-mails. But still no luck when trying to send e-mails from PHP mail() to the example.com e-mails.

So through this I've determined that the PHP mail() function works successfully in certain cases and the example.com emails do work with direct e-mails but when trying to use the PHP function there is an interruption and the e-mails don't come through. And yes, I have checked spam.

Any ideas on why this would be happening?

### EDIT

I have just found this article:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/55299?hl=en

Though I'm not sure exactly how to do what they say to resolve the issue:

```
To resolve this issue, notify the mail agent running on the server that hosts your website that it is not also responsible for handling mail for your domain.
```

How would I go about doing that on a VPS? Is this through the WHM?

### EDIT

One more thread here:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/V6AfTGHFKYI

It seems to suggest that Google Apps doesn't work with PHP mail() in a normal fashion?

Comment: Yeah thats a weird one, but its GoDaddy so yeah. Can you send ten emails using mail() via console to ten different email addresses and check them all and then send ten emails to 2 different email addresses. This should confirm for you if its a dns issue(does not know about certain domains) or if its a flood protectction issue(stop spamming) setup by godaddy.

Comment: Well I've tested it on three different e-mails outside of the example.com domain. I've even set up e-mails and sent them to two e-mails that were CC'ed and the 'To' field was an e-mail from the example.com domain and the CC'ed e-mails received it but the mail e-mail did not. Through the two threads I just posted as edits, this appears to be a Google Apps issue and not a GoDaddy issue?